# Search in all user's channel messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Can I use the Microsoft Graph API for Teams to search in messages of all channels the user has access to? I.e. can I use the API to build something like the search bar on top of the Microsoft Teams app?

Comment: hmm, i think that functionality is not exposed at this point (similar like search bar)... But for time being you can try this, you should get all the channels that you're part of. Then you make can make the [Graph API call to get list of messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality (similar like search bar) is not exposed at this point... But for time being you can try this, you should get all the channels that you're part of. Then you make can make the [Graph API call to get list of messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). In addition to that you can consider filing a [Microsoft Uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359626), so it can be considered as new feature request and can be implemented.